# RTSP streams play only sound, while local does video and sound

Tags: java, android

In my application, RTSP streams play only sound without video, but if i specify the video path as a local file, it plays the video and audio.

How would i get the RTSP streams to show video?

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Player.setVideoPath("rtsp://rtspvideohere.sdp");
    Player.start();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Android has built-in support for RTSP using the VideoView and MediaPlayer. It works very well on actual device - running it in emulator is problematic.

http://justdevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/10/video-streaming-with-android-phone.html

Here you can reach detailed information how to stream to android phone and which codecs are supported.

Probably something is wrong with your streaming server. Do you use the same file locally and on RTSP server? If not - codecs may differ and RTSP server is serving file with codecs that are not supported by Android.

Maybe try to capture network traffic (eg. using Wireshark) and show RTSP logs - there probably answer lies...